# Syntax on SQL statement with multiple conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am getting a run time 3075 issue on the following SQL string below. Is it possible I am missing parentheses?

```
    sql_get = 
"SELECT [tblCompetency02].[HighLevelObjective], 
[tblCompetency04].[Self], 
[tblCompetency04].[SelfSpecialLanguage], 
[tblCompetency04].[SelfChecklist], 
[tblCompetency04].[Team], 
[tblCompetency04].[TeamSpecialLanguage], 
[tblCompetency04].[TeamChecklist],
 [tblCompetency04].[Organisation],
 [tblCompetency04].[OrganisationSpecialLanguage], 
[tblCompetency04].[OrganisationChecklist],
 [tblCompetency02].[Competency] 
FROM [tblCompetency04] 
INNER JOIN [tblCompetency02] 
ON [tblCompetency04].[HighLevelObjective] = [tblCompetency02].[ID] 
WHERE [tblcompetency04].[self]<>"" or [tblcompetency04].[team]<>"" or [tblcompetency04].[organisation]<>"""
        Form_frmStaticDataSkills02.Form.RecordSource = sql_get
```

Comment: try sql_get=@"Select..........."; because inside the query there is doublequotes it will fail..if you use @ it will be fine..test and tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examine the `WHERE` clause of the statement your code creates.

Here's an Immediate window session:

```sql
sql_get = "WHERE [tblcompetency04].[self]<>"" or [tblcompetency04].[team]<>"" or [tblcompetency04].[organisation]<>"""
Debug.Print sql_get
WHERE [tblcompetency04].[self]<>" or [tblcompetency04].[team]<>" or [tblcompetency04].[organisation]<>"
```

Notice there is just one double quote character in each of these cases: `<>"`

If you want to have double quotes inside the string, use two to get one ...

```sql
sql_get = "WHERE [tblcompetency04].[self]<>"""" or [tblcompetency04].[team]<>"""" or [tblcompetency04].[organisation]<>"""""
Debug.Print sql_get
WHERE [tblcompetency04].[self]<>"" or [tblcompetency04].[team]<>"" or [tblcompetency04].[organisation]<>""
```

But I think it is less confusing and less error-prone to use single quotes inside the string ...

```sql
sql_get = "WHERE [tblcompetency04].[self]<>'' or [tblcompetency04].[team]<>'' or [tblcompetency04].[organisation]<>''"
Debug.Print sql_get
WHERE [tblcompetency04].[self]<>'' or [tblcompetency04].[team]<>'' or [tblcompetency04].[organisation]<>''
```